# Start a CSS animation only if another one is already finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 squares, i want to start the animation related to the red one only if the animation related to the blue on is already finished.

Which as a final result would be a cycle of animations.
How can i do that ?

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    
    position: absolute;
    

}

.red{
    background-color: red;
    top: 40%;
    -webkit-animation-name: example_red; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example_red;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    top: 10%;
    -webkit-animation-name: example_blue; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example_blue;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example_red {
    0%   {top:30%;}
    80% { top:42%;}
    100% { top:40%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example_red {
    0%   { top:30%;}
    80% {  top:42%;}
    100% { top:40%;}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example_blue {
    0%   { top:5%;}
    80% { top:12%;}
    100% { top:10%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example_blue {
    0%   { top:5%;}
    80% { top:12%;}
    100% { top:10%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box blue"></div>
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: add a delay to the second animation equal to the duration of the first ?

Comment: Yes it's logic, but i want something without having to count the duration of my animations.

Comment: consider the event `animationend` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I splitted the CSS `.red` rule in two, one for the color and size and the other to assign the animation. I made the same for `.blue`.

Then, on the `animationEnd` event, just toggle the `.animation` class for both `.box` elements to have an infinite "loop" effect.

On load, you need to start the thing by adding the `animation` class to one of the two `.box`. You can do it using jQuery (like I did) or directly in the markup.

```js
$(".box").on("animationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",function(){
  $(".box").toggleClass("animation");
});

$(".red").addClass("animation");
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.red{
    background-color: red;
    top: 40%;
}
.red.animation{
    -webkit-animation-name: example_red; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example_red;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    top: 10%;
}
.blue.animation{
    -webkit-animation-name: example_blue; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example_blue;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example_red {
    0%   {top:30%;}
    80% { top:42%;}
    100% { top:40%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example_red {
    0%   { top:30%;}
    80% {  top:42%;}
    100% { top:40%;}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example_blue {
    0%   { top:5%;}
    80% { top:12%;}
    100% { top:10%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example_blue {
    0%   { top:5%;}
    80% { top:12%;}
    100% { top:10%;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box blue"></div>
```

---

**Bonus question:**
To have 3 animated squares (or more), you can't just toggle classes. You need to have a counter to know which square just finished animating.

This counter will have to cycle from zero to the amount of `.box`... So it has to stay in range! The remainder operator `%` is useful here.

```js
var boxCounter = 0;

$(".box").on("animationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd",function(){
  $(".box").removeClass("animation");
  boxCounter = (boxCounter+1) % $(".box").length;
  $(".box").eq(boxCounter).addClass("animation");
});

$(".red").addClass("animation");
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.red{
    background-color: red;
    top: 40%;
}
.red.animation{
    -webkit-animation-name: example_red; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example_red;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    top: 10%;
}
.blue.animation{
    -webkit-animation-name: example_blue; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example_blue;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.green{
    background-color: green;
    top: 70%;
}
.green.animation{
    -webkit-animation-name: example_green; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example_green;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example_red {
    0%   {top:30%;}
    80% { top:42%;}
    100% { top:40%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example_red {
    0%   { top:30%;}
    80% {  top:42%;}
    100% { top:40%;}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example_blue {
    0%   { top:5%;}
    80% { top:12%;}
    100% { top:10%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example_blue {
    0%   { top:5%;}
    80% { top:12%;}
    100% { top:10%;}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example_green {
    0%   { top:75%;}
    80% { top:80%;}
    100% { top:75%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example_green {
    0%   { top:75%;}
    80% { top:80%;}
    100% { top:75%;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box green"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explanation as well :)

Comment: Can you explain where can i put a third square animation for example, when it comes to the JS ?

Comment: Thank you, this is very kind of you, can you explain how those 2 lines work:   1) boxCounter = (boxCounter+1) % $(".box").length;
  2) $(".box").eq(boxCounter).addClass("animation");

Comment: In short... There is 3 `.box`. But the index to target them is zero-based. So we have to count `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1...`. If you have `boxCounter = 2`. Adding 1 will make 3. We're out of range! But the remainder of 3 divided by 3 is zero. So that is the trick. Look for [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) and [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), which targets the index.